# IntelliJ: How to debug GAE and GWT at the same time?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt, intellij-idea

I am developing a small project using GAE and GWT in IntelliJ. One question I have is that I cannot debug both part at the same time.

I created a debug config for GWT and another one for GAE. If I debug with the GWT config, I cannot do anything with GAE and vice versa.

How an I config IntelliJ so that I can debug both technologies at the same time?

Many thanks

Comment: If you debug GWT, it will also debug the server side, including GAE code. You just need to setup the runtime config.

Comment: Which kinds of run configurations do you use to start the GWT and the GAE?